# AutoMapper - Determine Source Type from Destination Type

Tags: c#, automapper, viewmodel

I have inherited a project that uses ***AutoMapper*** and the ***AutoMapper.Attributes*** NuGet package. In the ViewModels the ***[MapsFrom...]*** Attributes were placed on properties to identify the mapping from the source property. Recently we re-architected the application, separating the Data Models into a separate C# library (they had all been located within the Website project), unfortunately ***AutoMapper.Attributes*** has a known bug where this breaks the ***[MapsFrom...]*** and related Attributes (they are ignored causing the properties in the ViewModel to end up Null).

The ***AutoMapper.Attributes*** project has officially been abandoned and the owner no longer recommends its use meaning ***this bug will never be fixed***, you can read about it here: https://github.com/schneidenbach/AutoMapper.Attributes/issues/26

That being said, we have a block of code that takes in a ViewModel Type, inspected the Custom Attributes on that type looking for the ***[MapsFrom...]***, and uses this to determine the Source Type for that ViewModel. We don't know the Source Type at runtime and need to determine, from the AutoMapper Mappings, what the Source Type of the object is (i.e. the Entity Framework DbSet that is set as the Source, via the ***CreateMap(...)***. This has proven elusive to solve, after much research i'm turning to you guys for help on this.

**What I Have:**

Here is what the method currently looks like, obviously this will no longer work as we have had to remove the [MapsFrom....] attributes:

```
    internal static Type GetSourceType(Type viewModelType)
    {
        if (!(viewModelType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MapsFromAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() is MapsFromAttribute mapsFromAttribute))
        {
            throw new Exception("The view model class named " + $"{viewModelType.Name} is not decorated with MapsFrom attribute");
        }

        var destinationType = mapsFromAttribute.SourceType;
        return destinationType;
    }
```

**What I need:**

I need to modify the method above so that when a ViewModel Type is passed into the method I can extract the source Type thats mapped to that ViewModel. Lets see an example, if we had the Mapping below:

```
  CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>();
```

When a ***UserViewModel*** is passed into the method I need to determine that its source Type is ***User*** (which just so happens to also be an EntityFramework DbSet but that doesn't really matter in terms of this discussion).

The ***FindTypeMapFor*** method (shown below) won't help because you have to provide it with the Source Entity, which is exactly what I'm trying to discover.

```
TypeMap typeMap = AutoMapper.Mapper.Instance.ConfigurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor(TDto, TEntity>();
```

---

***PLEASE NOTE:*** We are using AutoMapper version 8.0, we have all of our CreateMap(...) statements in **Profile** classes, we are *NOT* using Attributes anymore.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/AttributeBasedMaps.cs